# My laptop is extremely slow and HDD is always 100% engaged in Task Manager

Tags: hard-drive, task-manager

I have been searching for a solution for a while and read many discussions on the issue, including two threads on SuperUser:

[Laptop's disk usage is always 100% and freezes after few seconds](https://superuser.com/questions/849312/laptops-disk-usage-is-always-100-and-freezes-after-few-seconds)

[Windows 8.1 Update 1 Disk Usage 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/759152/windows-8-1-update-1-disk-usage-100)

However, none is conclusive. My Task Manager always shows 100% for Disk. I have recently re-installed Windows 10 and have not installed so many applications yet. My HDD is half empty. The laptop is a HP Pavilion DV6 with 12 GB of RAM and 7-8 years old. **I am not sure whether my HDD needs to be replaced**. As I said, I have read many discussions and followed everything that had something to do with viruses, anti-viruses, hibernation, etc, and none worked for me. **How can I decide whether the HDD is the reason?**

[image: My Task Manager]

Comment: If you truly still have spinning rust, you should seriously consider upgrading to a SSD. It will give you a *tremendous* speed boost for a very reasonable amount of money.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for the response. Would you consider that change? I mean, is there any way/test to make sure that is the reason? BTW, I compared it with my other laptop which stands at 6-7% hdd usage with much more software installed.

Comment: It’s just general advice, only loosely related to your question. I’m not saying that’s *the* reason, although it definitely is a factor. It’s not related to the amount of software installed but the amount of software *running*.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anything is wrong from the face of it. After reinstall, your laptop is now downloading all the updates that weren't included in the installer (MpSigStub).

Additionally, a lot of disk activity is attributed to googledrivesync. Did you already install Google Drive and sign in to it? If so, it is now probably trying to sync your cloud contents.to your harddrive, which in turn will cause a lot of disk activity.

Both processes should go down over time, how much time is not something that can be told up front.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I installed Windows a while ago. I have had this speed problem before and after reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

https://superuser.com/a/766300/571029

> ...combination of **Disabling Hibernation** and **Turning Off the Pagefile**...